# Why is ReCaptcha Showing "invalid-keys" Error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

When my page loads, the ReCapthca Widget immediately shows "invalid-keys" error. I checked the keys, even created new keys, copying and pasting them into my website solution. When I run the project from local, no error appears. When I run it from my development server, I get the error. I don't know if it matters or not, but I'm using the same keys throughout my project which I thought was allowed. Plus it wasn't a problem before, but now it is.

According to the ReCaptcha documentation, this means that the keys are no longer valid and I need to create new keys. I did that and put them in my code (copy & paste so I wouldn't get them wrong). I then checked for a space at the beginning and end of the key because I noticed previously that sometimes a space gets added when you copy the key. No luck here.

I also took the Captcha off the other pages to see if using the same keys on different pages was the problem. No luck there either.

I double and triple checked the keys and nothing is amiss.

```
<%--RECAPTCHA WIDGET V2-CHECKBOX--%>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MyCheckboxSiteKey"></div>
<br />

<%--RECAPTCHA WIDGET V2-INVISIBLE--%>
<div id="recaptcha class=g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MyInvisibleSiteKey" data-callback="BtnSubmit" data-size="invisible"></div>


private void RunV2Call()
{
    //Getting the Checkbox Server Side Response
    var sbi = new StringBuilder();
    sbi.Append("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=");

    //----  OUR RECAPTCHA WIDGET V2-INVISIBLE SECRET KEY
    var secretKey = "MyCheckboxSecretKey";
    sbi.Append(secretKey);

    //----  RESPONSE FROM RECAPTCHA CONTROL
    sbi.Append("&");
    sbi.Append("response=");
    var reCaptchaResponse = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
    sbi.Append(reCaptchaResponse);

    //CLIENT IP ADDRESS
    //----  THIS IP ADDRESS PART IS OPTIONAL. 
    //----  IF YOU DO NOT WANT TO SEND IP ADDRESS YOU CAN
    //----  SKIP OR COMMENT OUT OR REMOVE BELOW 4 LINES
    //----  ALSO COMMENT OUT OR REMOVE THE METHOD 'GetUserIp()'
    sbi.Append("&");
    sbi.Append("remoteip=");
    var clientIpAddress = GetUserIp();
    sbi.Append(clientIpAddress);

    //----  MAKE THE API CALL AND DETERMINE VALIDITY
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var uri = sbi.ToString();
        var json = client.DownloadString(uri);
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RecaptchaApiResponse));
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
        var result = serializer.ReadObject(ms) as RecaptchaApiResponse;

        //--- CHECK IF WE ARE ABLE TO CALL API OR NOT
        if (result == null)
        {
            lblResult.Text = "";
            lblResult.Text = "Captcha was unable to make the api call";
        }
        else //---- IF YES
        {
            //----  IF API CALL CONTAINS ERRORS
            if (result.ErrorCodes != null)
            {
                if (result.ErrorCodes.Count > 0)
                {
                     foreach (var error in result.ErrorCodes)
                     {
                         lblResult.Text = "";
                         lblResult.Text = "reCAPTCHA Error: " + error;
                         lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                     }
                 }
             }
             else //----    IF API DOES NOT CONTAIN ERRORS
             {
                 if (!result.Success) //----    IF CAPTCHA WAS UNSUCCESSFUL FOR SOME REASON
                 {
                     lblResult.Text = "";
                     lblResult.Text = "Captcha did not pass, please try again.";
                     lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                 }
                 else //---- IF SUCCESSFULLY VERFIED; DO THE REST OF YOUR LOGIC
                 {
                     lblResult.Text = "";
                     lblResult.Text = "Success";
                     lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

                     ClearInputs();
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}

private void RunViCall()
{
    var sbi = new StringBuilder();
    sbi.Append("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=");

    //----  OUR RECAPTCHA WIDGET V2-INVISIBLE SECRET KEY
    var secretKey = "MyInvisibleSecretKey";
    sbi.Append(secretKey);

    //----  RESPONSE FROM RECAPTCHA CONTROL
    sbi.Append("&");
    sbi.Append("response=");
    var reCaptchaResponse = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
    sbi.Append(reCaptchaResponse);

    //CLIENT IP ADDRESS
    //----  THIS IP ADDRESS PART IS OPTIONAL. 
    //----  IF YOU DO NOT WANT TO SEND IP ADDRESS YOU CAN
    //----  SKIP OR COMMENT OUT OR REMOVE BELOW 4 LINES
    //----  ALSO COMMENT OUT OR REMOVE THE METHOD 'GetUserIp()'
    sbi.Append("&");
    sbi.Append("remoteip=");
    var clientIpAddress = GetUserIp();
    sbi.Append(clientIpAddress);

    //----  MAKE THE API CALL AND DETERMINE VALIDITY
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var uri = sbi.ToString();
        var json = client.DownloadString(uri);
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RecaptchaApiResponse));
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
        var result = serializer.ReadObject(ms) as RecaptchaApiResponse;

        //--- CHECK IF WE ARE ABLE TO CALL API OR NOT
        if (result == null)
        {
            lblResult.Text = "";
            lblResult.Text = "Captcha was unable to make the api call";
        }
        else //---- IF YES
        {
            //----  IF API CALL CONTAINS ERRORS
            if (result.ErrorCodes != null)
            {
                if (result.ErrorCodes.Count > 0)
                {
                     foreach (var error in result.ErrorCodes)
                     {
                         lblResult.Text = "";
                         lblResult.Text = "reCAPTCHA Error: " + error;
                         lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                     }
                 }
             }
             else //----    IF API DOES NOT CONTAIN ERRORS
             {
                 if (!result.Success) //----    IF CAPTCHA WAS UNSUCCESSFUL FOR SOME REASON
                 {
                     lblResult.Text = "";
                     lblResult.Text = "Captcha did not pass, please try again.";
                     lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                 }
                 else //---- IF SUCCESSFULLY VERFIED; DO THE REST OF YOUR LOGIC
                 {
                     lblResult.Text = "";
                     lblResult.Text = "Success";
                     lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

                     ClearInputs();
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}

private object GetUserIp()
{
    var visitorsIpAddr = string.Empty;

    if (Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null)
    {
        visitorsIpAddr = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.UserHostAddress))
    {
        visitorsIpAddr = Request.UserHostAddress;
    }
    return visitorsIpAddr;
}

[DataContract]
public class RecaptchaApiResponse
{
    //STRUCT TO CAPTURE RECAPTCHA RESPONSE
    [DataMember(Name = "success")]
    Public bool Success;
    [DataMember(Name = "error-codes")]
    public List<string> ErrorCodes;
}
```

Previously, this code was working fine. I hadn't touched it in a couple of months because I had more of the site to develop. I came back to this code because I was developing another form that needed to have ReCaptcha enabled on it. I expected this to continue working until V2 got deprecated

Comment: What was the issue?